# How can I make the following C++ program faster?

Tags: c++, performance

Link to the problem - https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/freshers-challenge-2/challenges/counting-the-steps

The question is as follows - Find the number of prime numbers between a and b(including a and b,in case they are prime.)

I used the sieve of Eratosthenes to solve the problem, but I am getting timeout on two test cases.

Especially for one test case, where there are 10,000 numbers, my C++ program took around 10 seconds in CodeBLocks. I am inserting the code snippet below-

```
for(int i=2;i<=upperbound;i++)
{
    prime[i-2]=i;
}
int sq=sqrt(upperbound);
for(int i=0;prime[i]<=sq;i++)
{
    if(prime[i]!=0)
    {
        int j=i+prime[i];
        for(;j<m;j+=prime[i])
        {
            prime[j]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code snippet for the sieve. My outputs are all correct, but how can I make this program faster.

EDIT : The segmentation fault was solved after replacing upperbound with sq

Comment: You're calculating the `sqrt` (potentially expensive) and not actually using it at all.

Comment: A couple of things: you define `sq` but don't seem to use it; you use `m` but don't define it (in the snippet you've included).  Also, if one of the test cases causes a seg-fault, the output cannot be "all correct".  You should probably show more code and the test cases that are causing problems.

Comment: This doesn't look like a Sieve of Eratosthenes to me.  take a look at the pseudo code here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Implementation

Comment: Do you build in release mode? What's your compiler options? In particular, optimization options. Did you tried profiling?

Comment: Sqrt will kill it. You don't seem to be using the value returned either. If you know which square roots are being calculated you can replace the implementation with a lookup table maybe.

Comment: It looks like you're tracking every number, even the even numbers.   You know full well that (with the exception of 2), all prime numbers are odd.  You can track only odd numbers, and increment your loop with `i+=2`.

Comment: You're potentially spending a lot of time doing array lookups when you don't need to. Build your loop so you're looping over `i` from `i = 2`, not over `prime[i]`. (Don't worry about wasting two array elements.)

Comment: @NathanOliver Apparently this is some other guy's sieve: *Erasthones*

Comment: Sorry for the spelling mistake of  Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You are using `sqrt`, which can be time consuming, especially as it finds the double root. You don't even use `sq` afterwards.</s>

**Edit:** Try replacing `upperbound` by `sq` in your loop. It'll solve some speed concerns, but not the segfault which probably is the result from allocating too big a chunk of memory.

---

The problem with the sieve algorithm is that it allocates the full array, for all numbers.

Another way of finding primes is to check all number by dividing them by primes up until their square root. A simple optimisation to that algorithm is avoiding even numbers. And storing *only* the prime numbers in a structure.

```
int lastBound = 0; //avoids doing too many multiplications
vector<int> primes;

primes.push_back(2);

for (int i = 3; i <= upperbound; i+= 2) {
    bool prime = true;
    for(int j : primes) {
         if (j > lastBound && j * j > i) {
             lastBound = j;
             break;
         }

         if (i%j == 0) {
             prime = false;
             break;
         }
    }

    if (prime) {
        primes.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Then you have the primes in the list, you can convert it to an array like you had, a set, or whatever.

There are some dynamic allocations that could cause some delay, but for a `vector` of size `n` there are only O(log(n)) allocations. There could probably be further optimisations, but for your purpose it should be enough.

Comment: @g24l `emplace_back` would only be useful if the `vector` contained a class that took `int` as its non-copy constructor argument, here it's the same as `push_back`.

Comment: `foreach(int j, primes)` ?

Comment: @1nflktd: sorry, too used to Qt, I meant `for(int j: primes)`.

Comment: use `reserve()` to avoid reallocating the vector all the times.

Comment: Replacing one square root with plenty of moduluses *and* dynamic allocation is not a very good trade.

Comment: @Alex there is no way of knowing the size of the vector in advance - except that it's about O(n/log(n)). Anyway there are few dynamic allocations and as Bjarne Stroustrup said the gain you have when using `reserve` is less than what you'd expect.

Comment: @molbdnilo I edited the answer with your concerns, also there are typically "a bunch of moduluses" for number that are primes - or close.

Comment: I suspect `lastBound` is a pessimization. `if(j*j>i) break;` is already very efficient. Also, I'd consider unrolling for 3 as well (this means doing an i+=4 inside the loop and then repeasting the code, so you check 5,7,11,13,17,19,23,...)

Comment: @coyotte508 The sieve of Eratosthenes does not use the modulus or any other divisibility test, it only uses addition.

Comment: @molbdnilo sorry, i meant 'only' in my comment (as in, the algorithm i use typically uses a few moduluses per number, only a bunch of them if the number is prime or close)

Answer (score 0):

The only time swallower I see in your code is the use of `sqrt`.

You can use the [*digit by digit* method in base 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Example_2).

But it is a minor improvement.

You have to change your **algorithm** to achieve better results.
Search of prime numbers is a difficult problem and there is a lot of *least worst* solutions (for example you can use [pseudo-prime filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoprime)...)

Comment: The usual fix is to replace `x<sqrt(y)` by `x < 0 || x*x < y` which is a lot faster. And here you already know `x>0` so the first half of the replacement isn't even needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively storing the prime numbers twice in your array. `prime[i] == i+2`, so you can replace `int j=i+prime[i];` with `int j=i+(i+2);`.

Now, if you don't need the actual values anymore, you can store just a single bit: `std::vector<bool> prime(upperbound, true);`. This reduces the memory needed by 95% (probably), which makes it likely that your sieve fits in the CPU cache.

Saving 2 bits in the beginning of `prime` is a bad idea. A single `i-2` instruction elsewhere is going to take up at least a whole byte, and cost you actual runtime as well.